# Summation Problem, Need help to continue.

Tags: summation, summation-method

Im working on certain problem,  here is my effort:

[image]

My question is how do I continue this? any properties or rules could I use there?

I want to get the theta result for Brute Force String Matching algorithm which is O(mn)

I use this tutorial below as a reference to work on this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XkHbNi1ZL4

Comment: We can see a string of equalities but we have no idea what you're doing or where you're going with this.  You probably have time to explain before it's closed for improvement, if you move fast.  You should probably [review this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/29335) before further posting, too.

Comment: @rschwieb I made some edit there, hopefully it is help.

Comment: $m$ is constant in the sum so you can take it out of the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $m$ and $n$ are fixed, you can say $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-m} \sum_{j=0}^{m}1 = \sum_{i=0}^{n-m} (m+1) = (n-m+1)(m+1)$$ which is indeed $O(mn)$, at least if you assume $n\ge m\gt 0$